# How can I use the data in config file to get next value when define Feeders

Tags: karate

I want to get next value by config file which will change by environment.
But I found that when I executed the simualation class, we do not excute karate.config firstly.
So I cannot get the value when define Feeders.

Is there any way to execute karate.config firstly before defining Feeders?

Here is my part of code：
In karate.config define "environment" and "configJsonFile"

```
var  config = {
    environment: "dev",
}
config.configJsonFile = karate.readAsString('classpath:com/XXX/config-' + config.environment + '.json')
```

In feader.feature, get the value from karate.config

```
Feature: get a list of user account

  Scenario: get a list of user account
    * json config = karate.get('configJsonFile')
    * def userAccounts = config.userAccounts
```

In MockUtil.class

```
public class MockUtils {

    private static final List<String> userAccounts = (List) Runner.runFeature("classpath:com/XXX/feeder.feature", null, false).get("userAccounts");

    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    public static String getNextUserAccount() {
        return userAccount = userAccounts.get(counter.getAndIncrement() % userAccounts.size());
    }
}
```

In simulation.scala:

```
  System.err.println(MockUtils.getNextUserToken)
  val feeder = Iterator.continually(Map("userAccount" -> MockUtils.getNextUserAccount))
  create = scenario("create").feed(feeder).exec(karateFeature("classpath:XXX/XXX.feature"))

  setUp(
    create.inject(rampUsers(2) during (5 seconds)).protocols(protocol)
  )
```

When I executed this scala file, it will return error which not get value set in karate.config in file "feader.feature".

I tried to print log in karate.config, but no anything shown in console before execting  `System.err.println(MockUtils.getNextUserToken)` in file "simulation.scala".

If anything is not clear, please tell me. Thanks.

Reference: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#feeders

Expecting:
I can get the data by config file to set feader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even in Gatling, Karate should process the `karate-config.js` before any `Scenario`. If it is not happening, you may have some problem with your project structure.

Since your question is very complicated and hard to understand, I think you need to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Note that if you use the `Runner.runFeature()` API, you have to set the boolean flag to `true` to run `karate-config.js`: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#invoking-feature-files-using-the-java-api

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try best to explain my issue next time.
But Anyway you resolved my problem. Yes, I need to set evalKarateConfig as ture to run karate-cinfig.js.